# Error: variable-sized object may not be initialized in c language. Has the constant int anything to do with it?

Tags: c

This is an example from my textbook but it says error when I try to run it. I don't understand where the problem is.

```
const int n=20, d=11; 
int pergjigjet[n]={1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 8, 2, 7}; 
int denduri[ d ]={0};

for( int p=0; p<n; p++)
  ++denduri[pergjigjet[p]]; 

printf("vleresimi\tdenduria\n"); 
for(int v=1; v<d; v++)
  printf("%d\t\t\%d\n", v, denduri[v]);
```

The error it shows:

```
Compilation failed due to following error(s). main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:15:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
     int pergjigjet[n]={1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 8, 2, 7}; 
     ^
main.c:15:24: warning: excess elements in array initializer
     int pergjigjet[n]={1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 8, 2, 7}; 
                    ^
```

Comment: `variable-sized object may not be initialized`

Comment: `\%d` is also invalid (unknown escape sequence)

Comment: I'm beginning to think this text book isn't very good..

Comment: @MikeChristensen ^^

Answer (score 6):

This textbook is erroneous; the code is not valid C.

Per *6.7.9 Initialization*, ¶3:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

The array `pergjigjet` is a variable-length array because the expression for the number of elements, `n`, is not an *integer constant expression*. `const`-qualified objects are not constants; they are simply objects for which attempts to modify them are either (depending on the method used) constraint violations or undefined behavior.

You could fix it by replacing `const int n=20, d=11;` with `enum { n=20, d=11 };` or use of preprocessor macros (`#define n 20`) but this is generally considered bad style.

As noted by Mike Christensen in a comment, it seems this textbook is rather bad. It's likely that the author was actually writing in a C-like subset of C++, not in C. This code would be valid in C++, since in C++, such `n` is a constant.